# SQL Server Count Using C# Prepared Statement

Tags: c#, sql, count

Im trying to do a COUNT using C# 'Prepared Statements' but I get error: :

> *SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to
>   have an explicitly set non-zero Size*

Below is my code:

```
public int PreparedCheck(String email)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] WHERE Email=@val1", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Prepare();
    Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you didn't specify your parameter value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
```

I write `email` as a value because you pass it as a parameter to your `PreparedCheck` method but you never use it.

Answer (score 2):

Two errors. You don't set the value for the parameter, but you also don't set the size of the parameter as required by the Prepare method

```
SqlParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
p1.Value = email;
p1.Size = 255;  // This should be the size of the column EMail on the datatable
cmd.Prepare();
```

Simply setting the value of the parameter seems not to be enough for the Prepare method.
While the property size is changed to the string length passed as value, the error is still there and doesn't go away until you explicitly set the Size property to valid value.

This is from the REMARKS section on [SqlCommand.Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Before you call Prepare, specify the data type of each parameter in
>   the statement to be prepared. For each parameter that has a variable
>   length data type, you must set the Size property to the maximum size
>   needed. Prepare returns an error if these conditions are not met.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value for your parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email;
```